# TeX: Nesting hboxes in a vbox doesn't display as expected

Tags: tex

With the following plain TeX:

```
\hbox to \hsize {

\vbox to 2 true in {
aaa aaaaa aaaaa aaa aaaaa aaaa aaa aaaa aaa.  aaa aaaaa aaaaa aaa aaaaa aaaa aaa 
aaaa aaa aaa aaaaa aaaaa aaa aaaaa aaaa aaa aaaa aaa.  aaa aaaaa aaaaa aaa aaaaa 
aaaa aaa aaaa aaa.  }

\vbox to 2 true in {
bbb bbbbb bbbbb bbb bbbbb bbbb bbb bbbb bbb.  bbb bbbbb bbbbb bbb bbbbb bbbb bbb 
bbbb bbb bbb bbbbb bbbbb bbb bbbbb bbbb bbb bbbb bbb.  bbb bbbbb bbbbb bbb bbbbb 
bbbb bbb bbbb bbb.  }
}
```

the goal is to see two boxes side containing a paragraph or so of text. Except that when TeXed, the first vbox stretches to the full size of \hsize, squeezing the second vbox off the page.

Why doesn't this work as expected? There might be a better way to implement side-by-side paragraphs, but I'm still interested in what's wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

A line of text in a paragraph will always stretch to \hsize (the value of \hsize at the end of that paragraph). Thus, use for example:

```
\hbox to \hsize {
   \vbox to 3 true in {
     \hsize=3 true in
     \strut aaa aaaaa aaaaa aaa aaaaa aaaa aaa aaaa aaa. aaa aaaaa aaaaa aaa
     aaaaa aaaa aaa aaaa aaa aaa aaaaa aaaaa aaa aaaaa aaaa aaa aaaa aaa.
     aaa aaaaa aaaaa aaa aaaaa aaaa aaa aaaa aaa.\vfil
   }
   \hfil
   \vbox to 3 true in {
     \hsize=3 true in
     \strut bbb bbbbb bbbbb bbb bbbbb bbbb bbb bbbb bbb. bbb bbbbb bbbbb bbb
     bbbbb bbbb bbb bbbb bbb bbb bbbbb bbbbb bbb bbbbb bbbb bbb bbbb bbb.
     bbb bbbbb bbbbb bbb bbbbb bbbb bbb bbbb bbb.\vfil
   }
}
```